# How to restrict background click in Ionic confirmation popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic. I have created confirmation popup. I need to open popup only once by a button click. Must restrict background click if popup already opened. But here I can click the button if already popup opened. So need to restrict background click and avoid to open popup as multiple times. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance. I have mentioned my code.

```
<button ng-click="click()"></button>

$scope.click = function(){
$scope.stopService();``
}
    //Stop service confirm popup
    $scope.stopService = function () {
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
            title: 'Confirmation',
            template: 'Are you sure do you want to stop the current service?'
        });

        confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
            if (res) {              

            } else {                    

            }
        });    
    };
```

Comment: I have improved the grammar and flow of text and introduced the word "modal" to help with search discovery & understanding.  I have used the word "background" consistently instead of interchanging with "backdrop" to aid understanding.  Introduced a couple of line breaks to break down the wall of text that might've put people off reading the whole question, but, also, removed some blank lines & extra-indentation from code example to keep it condensed for viewing on smaller screens.

Comment: I'm not an Ionic dev but while checking that your question isn't a duplication on SO I found these resources, that might help you: two SO questions that aren't necessarily duplications of yours: [click here for the first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641718/open-ionic-modal-from-ionic-popup) and [here for the second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285472/how-to-open-up-an-ionic-modal-upon-click); and [click here for an Ionic resource about Ionic modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicModal/). They may not answer your question, but might help you get there...